# Why is YOLOv5 using CUDA when i have specified CPU?

Tags: yolov5

When i load a model with YOLOv5 and specify `'cpu'`, yolo is still using `'gpu'`. Why?

The code:

```
model = yolov5.load(model, device='cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

```
print('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

prints `cpu`

It is always writing the following message into the console which is quite annoying:

```
UserWarning: User provided device_type of 'cuda', but CUDA is not available. Disabling
  warnings.warn('User provided device_type of \'cuda\', but CUDA is not available. Disabling')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a PyTorch specific bug unrelated to YOLOv5. See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/72527